# What does the phrase "buff up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

What does the phrase "buff up" mean in the following sentence from the description of the game "Subway Surfers"?

> *In the game, every power-up is on an independent timer. If you go to the shop and **buff up** each one, they’ll last longer.*

It's also not clear if the phrase "each one" is used in reference to "power-ups" or "independent timer."

Answer (score 3):

["**buff up**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buff):

> Buff (video gaming), a change to a weapon or ability that deems it more viable for game balance.

So it means to make something more powerful, in this case, the power-up. "each one" refers to the "power-up", as the power-up relies on the timer, but you can't buff the timer as it is not "an item" in the game, so you buff the power-up *to give it more time* to last.